# Align divs horizontally in container with a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to align a few div elements next to each other inside a container div. The container should have a horizontal scrollbar.

[image]

I have tried different solutions, but each of them has different problems. Please note that I am looking for a "generic" solution.
This means it should work with

- any container height
- any number of children (which can differ in width)

1.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Problem: divs are not aligned properly when they don't have "similar" content.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k08m6y6e/

2.

```
float: left;
```

Problem: Boxes wrap - no scrollbar

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k08m6y6e/1/

3.

```
display: table-cell;
```

Problem: no scrollbars - this actually makes sense to me, but it means this will not solve my problem

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k08m6y6e/5/

4. flexbox; 
   Problem: min-width of children are ignored plus seems to be inconsistent across browsers (especially IE)

Can anybody help me to come up with a good solution?

--

### SOLUTION

Both answers provided here (from Michael and Andrei) work pretty well; thank you very much. Sadly I can only accept one.

Small note: Internet Explorer seems to have a problem with both solutions. The scrollbar is overlaying the content of the children and/or a small part of the bottom of the children is cut off. Chrome and Firefox work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `inline-block` you can use `vertical-align` to align the divs.

```css
#container {
  height:150px;
  width:400px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hdiv {
  border:solid 1px black;
  height:100%;
  min-width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="hdiv">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    Line 1 <br/>
    Line 2
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    <img src="https://www.google.at//images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="g" style="height:100px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you want to vertically align the content in each cell, you can use `inline-flex` instead of `inline-block`, and use `align-items: center` to center vertically. I also added `justify-content: center` to center horizontally.

```css
#container {
  height:150px;
  width:400px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hdiv {
  border:solid 1px black;
  height:100%;
  min-width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="hdiv">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    Line 1 <br/>
    Line 2
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    <img src="https://www.google.at//images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="g" style="height:100px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a good solution, but would it be possible to somehow vertically center the content of the children?

Comment: @Preli no, I don't see that in the requirements of your original post? You could introduce a new element inside of the children that wraps the content and uses `flex` or `table-cell` to vertically center the content. But you can use `inline-flex` instead of `inline-block` to do that without changing the markup, and everything else behaves the same http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZVyvd

Comment: You are right, that was not part of my initial requirements. I am just trying to figure out a way which keeps all my options open. The inline-flex solution works really well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox to the rescue:

```css
#container {
  height:150px;
  width:400px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.hdiv {
  border:solid 1px black;
  display:block;
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.hdiv img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="hdiv">
    Text
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    Line 1 <br/>
    Line 2
  </div>
  <div class="hdiv">
    <img src="https://www.google.at//images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="g" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @repzero Please notice I also removed the `height:100%` from children, so their height gets properly calculated when there's a scrollbar. If you want that, of course :). Happy coding!

Comment: Nice solution, but width of children seem to be ignored plus in Internet Explorer the bottom border is not visible because the child-divs seem to be too high (https://jsfiddle.net/3uzo95ym/4/)

Comment: @Preli I cleaned up the inline styles and added `flex-shrink:0`, as well as rules to display images properly.  See updated answer.